# Intervals v.s. Domains: when to use which and why?

Tags: core-language, assumptions, language-design, intervals, idiomatic-usage

> or: **How to use `Interval` correctly?**

Mathematica provides [these constructs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AssumptionsAndDomains.html) for various symbolic deductions tasks. Among those constructs are symbolic number sets termed *domains*, which are typically number fields constrained by some inequalities.

Intervals are as well constructs with set-like features: union and intersection arithmetics are supported. On the other hand, they are not handled as usual set objects, since these arithmetics have their separate names (`IntervalUnion` `IntervalIntersection` as opposed to ``` Union``Intersection ```); they even have their own containing test: `IntervalMemberQ` as opposed to the standard `MemberQ` which "domains" are allowed to enjoy.

Why is this the case?
Is there a rule of thumb to use `Interval` correctly?
What is the original intention for the design of `Interval`,
and why do they seem to be second-class objects compared to "domains"?
Is it a good idea to extensively use composite booleans of inequalities?

**some background**

I am working with statistic distributions and processes, and there are sevaral related `*Domain` functions:

```
In[1]:= Names["*Domain"]
(*Out[1]= {"CoefficientDomain", "DistributionDomain", "FunctionDomain", "ProcessStateDomain", "ProcessTimeDomain", "$MachineDomain"}*)
```

These functions are mostly undocumented (but do occur in documentations of other symbols); they usually returns a set represented as composites of intervals or composite booleans of inequalities.

Comment: (1) This is to address the "Why is this the case?" question. `Union` et al are designed for use on discrete sets represented as `List`s (or as discrete  sets all using the same non-`List` head). The `Interval` family, by contrast, is designed specifically to implement standard interval arithmetic. This is all fairly clear from the documentation...

Comment: (2) The rule of thumb for `Interval` and supporting functions is that one wants to do interval arithmetic on real-valued intervals. Supporting this in full generality is difficult since that would involve representing "exact" values for special functions in a way that could be reliably evaluated to arbitrarily high precision. But the implementation in Mathematica tends to work well for many special functions and most (perhaps all) elementary functions.